# Conditional block for params on macro xacro

Tags: urdf, ros-melodic, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering how can i use if condition in params on macro?
for example:

```
<xacro:macro name="leg" params="prefix suffix">
```

I want to use if condition about the suffix:

```
if suffix == left so create "A", but if suffix != left so create "A"
```

or the concept is like if-else condition in a programming language?

The documentation on ros wiki doesn’t explain that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349515/conditional-block-for-params-on-macro-xacro/) by [billynugrahas](https://answers.ros.org/users/48876/billynugrahas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2020-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Oh it solved, i added `<xacro:property name="suffix" value="left"/>` when i call the macro. it give the property name suffix to the value “kanan”, so i can execute the conditional block using `<xacro:if value="${suffix == 'left'}">`

---

Originally posted by [billynugrahas](https://answers.ros.org/users/48876/billynugrahas/) with karma: 40 on 2020-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [OzzieTheHead](https://answers.ros.org/users/13406/ozziethehead/) on 2021-03-30**:
Hi, could you please format your answer to be informative for everyone?

**Comment by [pepelepew71](https://answers.ros.org/users/53438/pepelepew71/) on 2022-04-19**:
<xacro:if value="${suffix == 'left'}">
code for create A
</xacro:if>

<xacro:unless value="${suffix == 'left'}">
code for create B
</xacro:unless>